# Silverlight 3 doesn't display a custom control's default template

Tags: silverlight-3.0, controls

Silverlight 3 doesn't display the default template for a custom control I'm working on.

I have three projects in my solution:

1. **CustomControl.Controls** - Silverlight Class Library
2. **CustomControl.Silverlight** - Silverlight Application
3. **CustomControl.Silverlight.Web** - Web Application

In CustomControl.Controls I have the following class:

```
[TemplateVisualState(Name = "Normal", GroupName = "FocusStates")]
public class SampleControl : ContentControl
{
    public SampleControl()
    {
        DefaultStyleKey = typeof(SampleControl);
    }

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
        UpdateVisualState(false);
    }

    void UpdateVisualState(bool useTransitions)
    {
        VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Normal", useTransitions);
    }
}
```

Themes/generic.xaml is configured as Embeded Resource and contains the following:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <Style TargetType="controls:SampleControl">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="controls:SampleControl">
                    <Border Background="Orange" CornerRadius="5" />
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

Finally I'm using the custom control inside MainPage.xaml in CustomControl.Silverlight:

```
<UserControl x:Class="CustomControl.Silverlight.MainPage"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:sample="clr-namespace:CustomControl.Controls;assembly=CustomControl.Controls"
             mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="640" d:DesignHeight="480">
    <StackPanel x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <sample:SampleControl Width="100" Height="200" />
        <Button Width="100" Height="200" Content="bar" />
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

In the browser the SampleControl isn't visible (it still occupies 200px in height, so it is there) and below it, a button is displayed.

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 SP1 + Silverlight 3 Tools.

Is there anything else I need to do so that the template defined in Themes/generic.xaml is applied to SampleControl?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I've found the problem. Themes/generic.xaml shouldn't be added as "Embeded Resource" but as "Resource".

Dumb error that took hours of my life. :(